# Using gradle to import mongodb - produces Cannot resolve symbol 'mongodb'

Tags: java, mongodb, gradle

I have added Gradle to my project and everything is linked up now, the project runs as normal if I don't include any code relating to mongodb.

Any import relating to mongodb (for instance `import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;`) produces the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'mongodb'`.

My `build.gradle` file looks like so:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.2.0-beta1'
}
```

In my project structure -> Libraries (intellij), I can see an entry for: `Gradle: org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.1.1` so I should assume the project should be able to use the mongodb lib?

Have I missed something out in using Gradle to import mongodb?

Comment: Just to clarify, you added in your build.gradle this dependency "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.2.0-beta1" but in your IntelliJ appears another version too?

Comment: @AndresSacco I have `org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.2.0-beta1` in build.gradle and no other versions elsewhere, when I try to implement mongodb Intellij cannot find anything under com.mongodb, and as far as i can tell it should see it, as it is included in the build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the project with intellij starting with gradle and all dependency issues were ironed out.